# Why when I redirect output to an existing file the system will make a new file?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have .bat file which finds the user login details with below code:

```
echo %computername%, %userdomain%, %username%, %date%, %time%
```

I have the file `log.csv` to store the information. This log file is available inside `C:\drive\tmp`.

When I redirect the output with like this:

```
echo %computername%, %userdomain%, %username%, %date%, %time% >> C:\drive\tmp\log.csv
```

The script does not store the output in the existing file log.csv, but instead it will make new log.csv with a duplicate name.

Why does this happen? What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Your command does not include the file name? `>> C:\drive\tmp\log.csv`

Comment: Do you mean there are two log.csv in `C:\drive\tmp`?

Comment: I took some liberties with a new title. If it's not reflective of your question, please [edit].

Comment: Is it the only string in your bat-file? Maybe there are commands wich remove your file before output?

Comment: Yes your right Dmitry . output not storing into the exsting log file, it will create one more new log1 file.

Comment: what you describe, is simply impossible with the code, you showed us.

Comment: I agree with @Stephan; I guess there is some more code in your batch file which causes the problem, so I suggest to add it as well...